# Python urllib2 request to https failing

Tags: python, soap, protocols, urllib2

I get this error:

EOF occurred in violation of protocol

when trying to talk to a SOAP endpoint

```
import urllib2
req = urllib2.Request(url='my_end_point')
ahh = urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue was SNI was enabled on the server I was trying to talk to. disabling SNI allowed me to connected. This solution is viable for me in the short term.

I spent hours googleing this!!!